# Any ideas about rate limit request/minute on Spotify Api?

Tags: spotify

Is there anyone using Spotify Web API on development website can provide any    approximate number about request/minute limits of Web API?

I'm using Client Authorization Flow

I've asked same question here: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Ongoing-Issues/Web-Api-Rate-Limit/idc-p/2121577#M54331, but no response given, i'm looking for someone that made some tests.

Thanks all

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a harness I just threw together, I called the individual track api endpoint with different values until it started to complain (the Spotipy Python library backs off and retries after a 429 automatically). Within a minute I was able to call it 600 times. It had to back off after about 270 tries,and 560 tries, but only for a second each time.

I repeated this test, for 1150 calls to the same endpoint, over the course of two minutes, again only having to back off for a second a few times.

At the very least this indicates that Spotify likely doesn't allocate meaningful rate limits on a per minute basis, but it's still possible that there is some kind of daily or hourly limit.